# How to activate relay when voltage rise threshold is reached

Tags: voltage-regulator

I've made a basic AC-to-DC converter, 120VAC in, 120VDC out, used for backup power to run a 120VDC deep-well solar-electric water pump when the sun isn't shining.

The AC power source for this backup system is always a gasoline-powered generator,  with several different ones of various sizes/ages/brands being available for use.  The problem with these generators is that their AC output voltage can vary quite a bit, depending on the generator's capacity, voltage regulation (or lack thereof) under various load demands, etc.

So, to protect the DC pump's controller from over-voltage damage, my idea is to install a relay, single-pole, double-throw, into the AC side of the converter,  which will activate to disconnect the converter output to the pump when overvoltage occurs. The target overvoltage threshold is 128VAC.

But I don't have enough electronics savvy to figure this out on my own. Solutions like simply putting a resistor in series with the relay coil isn't precise enough, and would always have the relay partially energized even during normal converter operation.

So I'm looking for a hopefully simple method to energize the relay when 128VAC is reached. This condition is removed by turning off the converter and lowering the generator voltage.

Converter specifics:  AC-In to isolation toroid transformer, approx 12 amps at 120VAC.  Then to full-wave bridge rectifier, with filter capacitor and bleed-off resistor. The relay in question has one AC line going to/through the Normally Closed contacts during normal converter operation.  But when overvoltage occurs and relay is activated, the Normally Closed contacts open, disconnecting the AC-In. At the same time, the relay's Normally Open contact receives the AC-in, energizing a red warning light on the converter's front cover.

Comment: this solution smells metastable.  1200W pump? how much hot water do you need?

Comment: Jasen, where did the OP mention hot water? Could be a well pump or simple transfer pump from one reservoir to another (for irrigation or livestock). My well pump draws 23 Amps at 240V AC when it is on, which, thankfully is probably only around 1 hour per day.

Comment: Good deduction, mkeith, it's a deep-well submersible pump, 1-1/2hp.. can get up to 1500 watts at max voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should build an auxiliary circuit in parallel with the main transformer and use that to 'measure' the AC voltage.

Get a simple isolation transformer with roughly a 1:9 turn ratio. It doesn't need to be have a high VA rating; it's only going to need to power a few ICs and the coil of your shutdown relay. You will have to check this transformer can cope with the overvoltage range you expect the generator to produce; you might even choose with a 220V one to allow some extra headroom while giving you a suitable output at normal operation.

Ultimately, you want a rectified and smoothed DC output at 12-15V for normal generator output (120VAC). The higher the DC output, potentially the more precise you can be with your cut-off voltage. However, if you get too high (above 15V probably) you will start to run into difficulties finding components that can be powered from such a high DC supply.

From here, you have a few options as to how you go about detecting the overvoltage. If you regulate the voltage to a stable 9-12V, you can use an op-amp comparator with one input at a precise voltage representing the raw DC @ 128V AC, and the other input connected to the smoothed (but *not* rectified) DC output from the transformer. Connect the output of the comparator through a transistor/MOSFET to drive the shutdown relay, and you have yourself some over voltage protection.

The above description may be a little coarse; I can provide a schematic if you require further embellishment. There are both finer and cruder alternatives if you want belt-and-braces protection or a minimum component count, respectively. I will happily entertain both methods if you want more information; I used the above example as it's a happy medium, and the one I'd use.

The important thing to remember, whichever method you use, is that you have your 'detector' circuit isolated from the main convertor. **And make sure** that you place the relay *contacts* such that they don't turn off the auxiliary transformer, only the main one!

Comment: Your solution sounds like a good way to go... but a bit beyond me as to what specific part numbers to use for the op-amp comparator and the driver transistor/MOSFET; and how it all wires together.  Your offer to share a schematic would also be most helpful. I could probably find a suitable transformer, but need to know relay coil power demand.  I like the 12vdc figure for this circuit, common parts.  Thanks for your ideas and time.

Comment: No problem, I only left out a schematic in the first place because it's such a pain in the backside doing one on my phone! I'll edit my answer from a PC later today, with some easy to find components (are you in the US? If not, where are you?). If you've managed to make an AC-DC convertor already, it won't be tough to do the rest.

Comment: Yes I'm in the USA.

Comment: I might have a simple solution for the regulated 12vdc. I've got several small 12vdc regulators.  The input is also 12vdc, the output is adjustable down to 0-vdc. I've tested these units and they hold their output voltage very steady.  They're about 2.5" x 2" x 1".  There's a mini toroid choke or transformer, some capacitors, and a flat looking little thing with 3 leads, mounted on an aluminum finned heat sink (scr, mosfet?). Anyway, I thought this might make the rest of the design simpler.